# form fill and submit without waiting for an event?

Tags: javascript, forms, events, submit

Using http://en.allexperts.com/q/Javascript-1520/create-form-submit-fly.htm as reference, I create the following form and it can be submitted by an onclick event or any other user-event? Is there a way to execute this when the page loads or do I have to wait for the user event always?

```
<script>
var params = something
//helper function to create the form
function getNewSubmitForm(){
    var submitForm = document.createElement("FORM");
    document.body.appendChild(submitForm);
    submitForm.method = "POST";
    return submitForm;
}

//helper function to add elements to the form
function createNewFormElement(inputForm, elementName, elementValue){
    var newElement = document.createElement("<input name='"+elementName+"' type='hidden'>");
    inputForm.appendChild(newElement);
    newElement.value = elementValue;
    return newElement;
}
function createFormAndSubmit(){
    var submitForm = getNewSubmitForm();
    createNewFormElement(submitForm, "field1", params.data1);
    createNewFormElement(submitForm, "field2", params.data2);
    submitForm.name= "submitpost";
    submitForm.action= "some URL";
    submitForm.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have got it working by hardcoding it using document.write and then filling values but a resolution for this would be nice and may help someone else... the moderators are welcome to remove this post if they deem that a better option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to do something like the following. Right?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var params = ["1","7"];
        createFormAndSubmit();

        //helper function to create the form
        function getNewSubmitForm(){
            var submitForm = document.createElement("FORM");
            document.body.appendChild(submitForm);
            submitForm.method = "POST";
            return submitForm;
        }

        //helper function to add elements to the form
        function createNewFormElement(inputForm, elementName, elementValue){
            var newElement = document.createElement("INPUT");
            newElement.name = elementName;
            newElement.type = 'hidden';
            newElement.value = elementValue;
            inputForm.appendChild(newElement); 
            return newElement;
        }

        function createFormAndSubmit(){
            var submitForm = getNewSubmitForm();
            createNewFormElement(submitForm, "field1", params[0]);
            createNewFormElement(submitForm, "field2", params[1]);
            submitForm.name= "submitpost";
            submitForm.action= "show.jsp";
            submitForm.submit();
        }

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: i dont know why but that doesn't seem to work. I think it should! but it doesn't... i did try that before :D apparently you have to wait for a user event no matter what.

Comment: Really? For me this worked without waiting for some user event. On loading the page that contains this code the form gets immediately submitted and I see the result in another page, show.jsp. What happens in your case?